# getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the coordinates of the mouse-click on a image.
So I'm using getBoundingClientRect like this

```js
function showCoords(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
}
```

But I get this error "canvas.getBoundingClientRect is not a function"

Comment: really depends on how you call `showCoords` - what do you pass as the first argument

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That means that `canvas` variable is not actually a Canvas element.

It can be `undefined`, still not initialized or incorrectly selected.

You need to double check it and maybe try to use `event.target` if the click event is added to the canvas element.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working by calling like this : <img src="image.jpeg" id="img" onclick="showCoords(document.getElementById('img'),event)">